Schema drift in Spark Databricks Automerge.enabled
I am working on an ingestion of a series of json files, each of which represents a single row while flattened out in a proper tabular form / single dataframe. I am using a Delta table from Bronze Layer to Silver layer (where the flattening happens).However, the headers of the jsons are dynamically changing and I am using the following code to "serve my schema drift" needs, but is not working accordingly:
Enable schema auto-evolution
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true")

# Load the Delta table
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, targetPath)

deltaTable \
    .alias("tgt") \
    .merge(
    rawDf.alias("src"),
    mergeCondition
) \
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set=columns_to_update) \
    .whenNotMatchedInsert(values=columns_to_insert) \
    .execute() 

Somehow it returens an error when a new column appears.Any thoughts on how to fix it:
ERROR: Cannot resolve tgt.ABC in UPDATE clause given columns src.columns

Code is incomplete. Where is columns_to_update? Provide example json files.
